# Прописные буквы

Tags: орфография

Иногда с оттенком иронии человеку могут дать какое-то прозвище, вроде "господин Ничего-не-знаю" или что-то в этом роде. То, что все слова этого прозвища будут писаться через дефис, понятно, но что из этих слов должно писаться со строчной буквы?

Answer (score 1):

Первая часть начинается с прописной буквы, вторая же, если она есть, пишется со строчной буквы и присоединяется к первой дефисом.
P.S :Индивидуальные названия людей, превратившиеся из имен собственных в имена нарицательные, пишутся со строчной буквы, например: ловелас, донжуан, меценат, ментор.
Но если такие названия людей лишь употребляются в нарицательном смысле, но не превратились в имена нарицательные, то они пишутся с прописной буквы, например: Может собственных Платонов и быстрых разумом Невтонов Российская земля рождать (Ломоносов); Не каждый день рождаются Гоголи и Щедрины.
Индивидуальные названия людей, употребляющиеся в презрительном смысле как родовое название, пишутся со строчной буквы, например: азефы, квислинги.